# Magento 2 - Show custom Block on Cart Page

Tags: magento2, cart, blocks

**Namespacee/Modulename/Block/Productpoint.php**

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block;

class Productpoint extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


}
```

**Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block template="checkout/cart/productpoint.phtml" class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Productpoint" name="productpoints.cart.block" as="productpointblock" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/checkout/cart/productpoint.phtml**

```
<span><?php echo 'Eureka'; ?></span>
```

The block is not loading on cart page. How do I call my custom block on cart page ?

Comment: check system.log in var/log folder and _prepareLayout() function is not needed

Comment: Is the template rendering correctly? If not it may be worth trying to add the namespace and module name before the template like so:

<block template="Namespace_Modulename::checkout/cart/productpoint.phtml"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rewrite checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Productpoint" before="-" template="Namespace_Modulename::checkout/cart/productpoint.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now the block will be displayed on top of shopping cart.

Comment: `system.log` says `main.CRITICAL: Invalid method Ei\Productpoint\Block\Productpoint::__(Array
(
    [0] => Redeem Credit Points
))` I have already removed `_prepareLayout` method

Comment: you can restore `_prepareLayout` method and check