# Magento 2 - Delivery Note on Cart Page

Tags: magento-2.1, addtocart

My requirement is, to add Delivery Note section in cart page, I have an idea, when click "proceed to checkout" want to add it to cart session then checkout success should it save with order.

Any one have any idea about this, please give me an idea and events.

Answer (score 2):

**Here's my idea:**

1. Create custom attribute for quote to save your delivery note [reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/131969/48564)
2. Add new block layout to cart page to show form containing the delivery note input text [reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/104527/48564)
3. Create controller to catch the form post data to save the delivery note input to quote custom attribute  [reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/149835/48564)
4. To retrieve the delivery note data you can call quote resource model and get the custom attribute value

Comment: thanks @Idham Choudry , 1st I want to add value to cart session - so whats the event for proceed to checkout then add it value to session. after all place order event to add order tables. can you please specify the events and add to session code,

Comment: Use 'checkout_cart_save_before'  event for updating the cart and use 'sales_order_save_after' event for saving the order.

Comment: @ssk8323 you can modify proceed to checkout button with javascript to prevent the default function which is redirecting to checkout page, you can make the button run ajax to save the note delivery data, then you can redirect to checkout page

Comment: @D Singh , @Idham Choudry  - I'll try and let you know.Thanks